# How to use external database (AWS RDS) with Bitnami Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, amazon-rds, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm trying to use [Bitnami Keycloak Helm](https://bitnami.com/stack/keycloak/helm), which has an internal dependency on Bitnami PostgreSQL that I cannot use. I have to use our existing RDS as an external DB, which seems possible but instruction on [this page](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/apps/keycloak/configuration/use-external-database/) is completely empty. Unfortunately, I can only use the Bitnami helm for Keycloak, FYI. Can anyone point me to the right direction or show what and where to change the stock chart to make it happen pls? Not getting much luck with Google atm.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a sidecar container which will handle authorization and proxy the db calls from keycloak to your managed database :

[keycloak] --localhost:XXXX-> [sidecar container] -> [Aws RDS]

You'll find documentation for this on the bitnami chart github repo : https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/keycloak#use-sidecars-and-init-containers

Comment: Link is broken..

Comment: Broken link fixed.

Answer (score 0):

On the stock chart, you can set these properties:

```
postgresql:
  enabled: false
externalDatabase:
  host: ${DB_URL}
  port: ${DB_PORT}
  user: ${DB_USERNAME}
  database: ${DB_NAME} 
  password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

If you need high availability, i.e will be running keycloak with multiple replicas, add the below as well:

```
cache:
  enabled: true
extraEnvVars:
  - name: KC_CACHE
    value: ispn
  - name: KC_CACHE_STACK
    value: kubernetes
  - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL
    value: "JDBC_PING"
```

Sources:

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/keycloak/#keycloak-cache-parameters

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/keycloak/#database-parameters

https://www.keycloak.org/server/caching#_relevant_options

Comment: Can you share an example of the stock chart that you have mentioned above?

Comment: The stock chart I'm referring to is the one OP posted which is at https://bitnami.com/stack/keycloak/helm.

Comment: Okay. I got confused with the terminology. Anyways, I ended up using Keycloak's instructions and building my own yml configurations to achieve all the possible customisations. Happy with my choice.